# Oracle-Drools integration possible?

Tags: oracle, integration, drools

I have some [Drools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drools) files.
I would like these Drools files to act on certain records in the Oracle database and then their outcome must update or insert certain records.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Drools is reactionary tool. While inserting the objects, drools creates a rete tree to fire the THEN condition at the time of firing the rules. Hence, You will have to assert the objects in working memory to fire the rules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either load the records from the database and insert them into the knowledge base before you run the rules or you can use the "from" keyword to get the records during rule execution time.

Here is an example how you can get the records from the database using "from" and Hibernate:

```
# Hibernate session is a global    
global org.hibernate.Session hibernateSession;

rule "hibernate_from"
    when
        game:Game() from hibernateSession.createQuery("select games from Player p where p.age >= :age").setProperties( {"age" : 18 }).list()
    then

        # This is the condition part of the rule, it contains MVEL or in this case Java code
        System.out.println("The game "+game.getName() +"is owned by "+game.getPlayers());
end
```

Updating and inserting the records can be done in the condition section of the Drools rule. This part of the rule can be written in the same way as any Java program.

For more information about "from" check the following:

[Drools documentation](http://www.jboss.org/drools/documentation)

[Jaroslaw Kijanowski's blog](http://magazine.redhat.com/2008/07/11/jboss-drools-meets-hibernate/)

[Drools & jBPM blog](http://blog.athico.com/2007/06/chained-from-accumulate-collect.html)